# How to include correct libssl version into yocto-build to run .net-core application?

Tags: .net-core, openssl, raspberry-pi3, yocto

I want to run a self contained .net-core application on a custom embeeded linux (on a raspberry pi 3 board). To build the linux distribution I use yocto (thud branch) with the meta-raspberry layer. 
To fullfill the depdencies for .net-core, I created a image recipes which includes the additional packages described here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/YoctoInstructions.md

"libunwind icu libcurl openssl"

The yocto build finsihes succesfully. But if I run my self contained .net-core applicaiton, I get a error message 
"No usable libssl was found" and the application is terminated.

I checked the libssl deployment in the rootfs. Libssl is there, but I think in the wrong version: libssl.so.1.1. 
If I get it correct, .net-core needs openssl in version 1.0. So I tried to include the openssl10 package into my image.

This is my current image-recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Linux Image which supports .net executables"

include recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb

IMAGE_INSTALL += "libunwind icu libcurl openssl10 curl"


LICENSE = "MIT"
```

Also the image build finishes successful. But only libssl.so.1.1 is included into the rootfs.

Is it not possible to install openssl in two different versions? (libssl.so.1.1 is pulled in by some other recipes)
Or maybe, it's not a version problem, but some other depdency problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the .net application is packaged via a Yocto recipe, add an openssl10 dependency to that.

Otherwise use:
IMAGE_INSTALL += "libunwind icu libcurl libssl10 curl"

(libssl10, not openssl10)

Comment: thanks, that worked. 
So, libssl10 was not pulled in, because there was no runtime depdency by other packages? ... And if I refere direct to the shared-library it is "hard-included" into the image?